# How can I read JSON files from SVN in Ruby/Chef code without checking the files out

Tags: ruby, json, svn, chef-infra

In my chef code, I am trying to read JSON files, parsing them and using their values. Currently I am doing it from my local machine. I want to be able to store the JSONs on SVN and give my code the path to the SVN location and it should be able to read it. Currently my code looks like this:

```
def get_json(template_name)
      big_json = JSON.parse(::File::read(new_resource.local_path + template_name))
      return big_json
end
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
def get_json(template_name)
      big_json = JSON.parse(::File::read(new_resource.svn_path + template_name))
      return big_json
end
```

Anyone know how I can directly do it though SVN?

Comment: wha is the "new_resource" ?

Comment: that's chef specific thing. The value is passed. Assume that it is passed to the function itself.

Comment: Is your SVN repo accessible via http(s)?

Comment: yes. It is. I can view the JSONs in a browser

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON file is available via HTTP, then something like the following *should* work:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

def get_json(template_name)
  open(new_resource.svn_path + template_name) do |f|
    return JSON.parse(f.read)
  end
end
```

Comment: Getting the following error when I do that:

 Error executing action `create` on resource 'cccis-environment-cookbook-machines[Creating Environment..]'
    ================================================================================
    
    Errno::EINVAL
    -------------
    Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - http://{svn location hidden}/environment.json

Comment: Probably got something to do with the argument you're passing to `open` - but that's a bit difficult for me to debug without seeing what you've got there exactly.